# Launch theme causing reboot

Tags: android, google-play-services, launching-application

I want to make good use of the "cold start" time by showing a branded launch theme, exactly as described [in this post](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/Z1Wwainpjhd).
I followed every step, but when launching the app, both the emualtor and a real device do a hot reboot.
I believe it is something related to Google Play Services, which I use in the app.
I tried to run [this](https://github.com/warting/LoaderScreen) project which follows the above post as well and doesn't include play services, and it's all fine, so it's not device-related.
Here's some code:

Manifest.xml

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Launch">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.Launch" parent="AppTheme" >
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg_launch</item>
</style>
```

bg_launch.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:opacity="opaque">

<item android:drawable="?android:windowBackground" />
<item>
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_logo"
        android:gravity="center" />
</item>
```

build.gradle (plugin version: 2.0.0-alpha6)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.rocca.app"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "0.9"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setUpGoogleApiClient(); //for IAB
    setUpAds();
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
android:id="@+id/root">

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/ad_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="..." />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ad_view"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                             Process: com.rocca.ringapp, PID: 5553
                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Package manager has died
                                                                 at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.hasSystemFeature(ApplicationPackageManager.java:413)
                                                                 at org.chromium.android_webview.AwSettings.<init>(AwSettings.java:232)
                                                                 at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.init(WebViewChromium.java:232)
                                                                 at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:606)
                                                                 at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:542)
                                                                 at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:525)
                                                                 at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:512)
                                                                 at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:502)
                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.u.k.<init>(SourceFile:227)
                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.u.k.a(SourceFile:204)
                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.u.i.a(SourceFile:52)
                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.d.a(SourceFile:76)
                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.n.a(SourceFile:100)
                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.g.run(SourceFile:196)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                              Caused by: android.os.DeadObjectException
                                                                 at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                                                                 at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
                                                                 at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.hasSystemFeature(IPackageManager.java:4264)
                                                                 at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.hasSystemFeature(ApplicationPackageManager.java:411)
                                                                 at org.chromium.android_webview.AwSettings.<init>(AwSettings.java:232) 
                                                                 at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.init(WebViewChromium.java:232) 
                                                                 at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:606) 
                                                                 at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:542) 
                                                                 at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:525) 
                                                                 at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:512) 
                                                                 at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:502) 
                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.u.k.<init>(SourceFile:227) 
                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.u.k.a(SourceFile:204) 
                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.u.i.a(SourceFile:52) 
                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.d.a(SourceFile:76) 
                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.n.a(SourceFile:100) 
                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.g.run(SourceFile:196) 
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Based on the Official Google Documentation, 'DeadObjectException' means that your service had already stopped. Either killed from the Operating System or stopped from your application. 

Override your service's onDestroy() method and watch what event flow leads to it. If you catch DeadObjectException without going through this method, your service should have been killed by the OS.

Comment: I don't use any service of my own. It seems it's something related to AdMob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in bg_launch.xml, at `android:drawable="?android:windowBackground"`.

Changing the `<item>` into

```
<item>
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/grey_50" />
</shape>
</item>
```

somehow makes it work.